# Query returning same sums - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Wonder if anyone can shed any light on a sql query I'm working with;

I have built this query;

```
SELECT  SUM(TICKET_TYPE.PRICE) AS TOTALCINEMASALES, CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
FROM    RESERVATION, TICKET, TICKET_TYPE, CINEMA, PERFORMANCE
WHERE   TICKET_TYPE.TICKET_TYPE_ID = TICKET.TICKET_TYPE_ID
        AND TICKET.RESERVATION_ID = RESERVATION.RESERVATION_ID
        AND RESERVATION.PERFORMANCE_ID = PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_ID
        AND CINEMA.LOCATION = 'SKIPTON'
        AND PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01/03/2009','DD/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('07/04/2009','DD/MM/yyyy')
GROUP BY
       CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
ORDER BY
       TOTALCINEMASALES;
```

Every time I run it, it returns the sam set of sums on each row for totalcinemasales, but I know there are different levels of tickets sales etc sat in the database, it does it for every loaction I change, any pointers as to how I could improve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to join CINEMA, probably with PERFORMANCE.

Guess:

```
AND CINEMA.CINEMA_ID = PERFORMANCE.CINEMA_ID
```

You could use the ANSI joins, when you get used to it, it is actually easier to read:

```
SELECT  SUM(TICKET_TYPE.PRICE) AS TOTALCINEMASALES, CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
FROM    
   TICKET 
   inner join TICKET_TYPE
     on TICKET_TYPE.TICKET_TYPE_ID = TICKET.TICKET_TYPE_ID
   inner join RESERVATION
     on TICKET.RESERVATION_ID = RESERVATION.RESERVATION_ID
   inner join PERFORMANCE
     on RESERVATION.PERFORMANCE_ID = PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_ID
   inner join CINEMA  /* the missing link */
     on CINEMA.CINEMA_ID = PERFORMANCE.CINEMA_ID
WHERE
   CINEMA.LOCATION = 'SKIPTON'
   AND PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01/03/2009','DD/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('07/04/2009','DD/MM/yyyy')
GROUP BY
       CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
ORDER BY
       TOTALCINEMASALES;
```

Comment: Thanks, what you can't see is (probably the reason for the problem after reading your suggestion) is that there is no direct link from performance to cinema, I have used cinema>screen(cinema_id)>run(screen_id>>performance(run_id) - Should I be including both those tables and adding 'and' for the links? or ansi joins, allthoug i feel I need to get my heard around that a littl more.

Comment: Yes, you need to join all the tables. If you don't, you get a Cartesian Product, this means that all combinations of Cinema and the joined other tables are returned. To see what I mean, remove the group by clause and the SUM from the select clause. With the filter, you remove all useless combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUM(TICKET_TYPE.PRICE) AS TOTALCINEMASALES, CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
FROM    RESERVATION, TICKET, TICKET_TYPE, CINEMA, PERFORMANCE
WHERE   TICKET_TYPE.TICKET_TYPE_ID = TICKET.TICKET_TYPE_ID
        AND TICKET.RESERVATION_ID = RESERVATION.RESERVATION_ID
        AND RESERVATION.PERFORMANCE_ID = PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_ID
        AND CINEMA.LOCATION = 'SKIPTON'
-- Added this
        AND PERFORMANCE.CINEMA_ID = CINEMA.CINEMA_ID
--
        AND PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01/03/2009','DD/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('07/04/2009','DD/MM/yyyy')
GROUP BY
        CINEMA.LOCATION, PERFORMANCE.PERFORMANCE_DATE
ORDER BY
        TOTALCINEMASALES;
```